# how to print on a JPanel / JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, arrays

So my code prints players names and scores all vertically on the JPanel, all the players first, then all their scores. I want to know how to print one after another alongside their scores. For Example.

```
Name1 Score1
Name2 Score2
Name3 Score3
Name4 Score4
```

My code is made for top 10 players/scores so i use arrays for this method. My code is :

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
         {
            JSingleplayer[x] = new JLabel (Singleplayer[x]);
            EndPanelplayer.add(JSingleplayer[x],BorderLayout.EAST);
            JSingleScore[x] = new JLabel (SingleScore[x]);
            EndPanelscore.add(JSingleScore[x],BorderLayout.WEST);
         }
            EndFrame.add(EndPanelplayer);
            EndFrame.add(EndPanelscore);
```

As you can see, i have 2 panels. I set one east and one west but that did not work. I also tried south for both. I need help fixing my code or adding additional code in order for it to print vertically with its mate. Thanks in advance!

Comment: nope, that was how to print in JLabel, but it printed out all horizontal like i mentioned in question. I need another way to print this out. Thanks for your concern thou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `JTable`.

See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information and working examples.

Also, follow Java naming conventions. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: 1+ Yep, as I recommended in comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23599570/522444), a thread you should have a look at Rob. Glad he's finally coming around.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to line up labels and or fields, your immediate first thought should be to use the [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

You should also use lower case to start a Java field.  Here are the [Java Naming Conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm).

And here's your code.  You'll need to set the layout when you define the JPanel.

```
private static final Insets bottomInsets    = 
        new Insets(0, 0, 6, 0);

private void addLabels() {
    int gridy = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        jSingleplayer[x] = new JLabel(singleplayer[x]);
        addComponent(mainPanel, jSingleScore[x], 0, gridy, 1, 1,
                bottomInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE);

        jSingleScore[x] = new JLabel(singleScore[x]);
        addComponent(mainPanel, jSingleScore[x], 1, gridy++, 1, 1,
                bottomInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE);
    }
}

private void addComponent(Container container, Component component,
        int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight, 
        Insets insets, int anchor, int fill) {
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(gridx, gridy,
            gridwidth, gridheight, 1.0D, 1.0D, anchor, fill, 
            insets, 0, 0);
    container.add(component, gbc);
}
```